# Splitting up selecting an element inside an atom and updating it without sacrificing safe concurrency.

Tags: concurrency, clojure, swap

Say I have a data structure contained in an atom and I would first like to select an element of it and then update this element. I could do both operations inside a single swap!, which is correct with respect to race conditions and other nasty things, but does not allow for much concurrency. Is there a better solution?

In the following example, the code is slowed down a lot because the looked up value is regularly modified (every 50ms), thus needing the swap! to rollback. The

```
(swap! myAtom
    (fn [atom-state]
        (let [lookedUp (searchValIn atom-state)] ;This slows down the code
            (if (*some condition*)
                lookedUp
                (modify lookedUp)))))
```

In other words: I'm looking to split up selecting the element and updating it without sacrificing safe concurrency.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the conditions under which you want to perform the updates?

Comment: Given the atom is changing so frequently, the lookedUp value gets invalidated quickly. So the question is perhaps: What do you want to happen if it gets invalidated? Do you want to re-run the calculation and try again? If so, your code is best. But if you'd rather abort once you discover it is invalidated by another thread updating the atom, there might be better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, it is not possible. In order to maintain consistent view of data, you need to do lookup and perform update inside single "transaction" (in quotes, because `transaction` term does not apply well to atom manipulations).